# Destructing Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs, destructuring

My data look likes below

```
0:
comment: Array(3)
0: {userName: "user1", userPic: "https://i.imgur.com/NYPDStw.jpg", comment: "testing", date: "Mon Aug 02 2021 22:37:38 GMT+0800 "}
1: {userName: "user1", userPic: "https://i.imgur.com/NYPDStw.jpg", comment: "testing", date: "Mon Aug 02 2021 22:37:38 GMT+0800 "}
2: {userName: "user1", userPic: "https://i.imgur.com/NYPDStw.jpg", comment: "testing", date: "Mon Aug 02 2021 22:37:38 GMT+0800 "}
createdAt: "2021-07-23T06:20:34.960Z"
desc: "test"
img: "https://i.imgur.com/NHkPn0V.jpg"
likes: []
updatedAt: "2021-08-02T14:50:12.475Z"
userId: "60fa062b14047b0015e45e35"
__v: 0
_id: "60fa5fb2e89926001532cbe7"
```

when there's no 'comment' in the data everything works fine, but after I add comment into the data,it reports the error.
Here's the code  where I destructing my data

```
const fetchData = async () => {
  setPage(page + 1);
  const fetchPosts = async () => {
    const res = username
      ? await axios.get("/api/posts/profile/" + username + "/" + page)
      : await axios.get("/api/posts/timeline/all/" + page);
    let data = "";

    data = res.data; //here return all the datas
    data = data.sort((p1, p2) => {
      return new Date(p2.createdAt) - new Date(p1.createdAt);
    });
    console.log(data);
    setPosts((prevPosts) => {
      return [...prevPosts, ...data];
    });
  };
  fetchPosts();
};

return (
  <div className="feed">
    <div className="feedWrapper">
      {(!username || username === user.username) && <Share />}
      <InfiniteScroll
        dataLength={posts.length} //This is important field to render the next data
        next={fetchData}
        hasMore={hasMore}
        loader={
          <div className="onLoading">
            <CircularProgress color="gray" size="30px" />
          </div>
        }
        endMessage={
          <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
            <b>No other article！</b>
          </p>
        }
      >
        {posts.map((p) => (
          <Post key={p._id} post={p} />
        ))}
      </InfiniteScroll>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

so I think it has something to do with destructing,but I don't know how to fix this. it went wrong at

```
setPosts((prevPosts) => {
      return [...prevPosts, ...data];
    });
```

the message return

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {userName, userPic, comment, date}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: I think `page` is not updated so quickly. Is `data` the expected result/array? What does console.log say?

Comment: Which part has the destruturing in it?